# What's the difference between "screenplay by" and "story by"?

Tags: screenplay, adaptation

I am wondering if the story on which the 2018 film *[Christopher Robin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christopher_Robin_(film))* is based has been published anywhere, and it appears not. Its Wikipedia page states:

> Christopher Robin is a 2018 American fantasy comedy-drama film directed by Marc Forster and written by Alex Ross Perry, Tom McCarthy, and Allison Schroeder, from a story by Greg Brooker and Mark Steven Johnson.

> **Screenplay by**: Alex Ross Perry, Tom McCarthy, Allison Schroeder
> **Story by**    Greg Brooker, Mark Steven Johnson
> **Based on**: Characters from: Disney's Winnie the Pooh, Winnie-the-Pooh books, by A. A. Milne, E. H. Shepard

However, [this file I found online](http://www.wdsmediafile.com/media/ChristopherRobin/writen-material/ChristopherRobin5b087f2ba1cd8.pdf) allegedly from Disney doesn't credit Brooker and Johnson. Wikipedia claims they are co-recipients of the Humanitas Prize together with the screenwriters. So what is the difference between "story by" and "screenplay by" (if the *story* **does not refer to the original story**)? "Based on" is easier to understand in this context.

Comment: I’m not an expert but I think “story by” indicates creative input equivalent to a plot summary. “Screenplay by” indicates an actual script with dialog and action descriptions. Notice this “based on” credit starts with the word “characters”, which is distinct from plot. That means the plot was at least partly devised by the “story by” people and the characters that inhabited that plot where taken from works written by the “based on” people.

Comment: Please do not answer a question in a comment. This avoids standard editing and voting.